# Database : update operation result in data logic loss

Tags: database-design

I do some inserts in another tables based on column value in a table (e.g initial balance) -- later, if  the user change that value of (initial balance column) -- the old inserts will be not logic --and i want not to lock the update -- how to solve this problem ???

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Also consider to include sample data and desired result.

Comment: i mean : Based on value X of column you make paths of insert and update in another tables
But if you change that value later ? previous operation will be now not logical

Comment: You are unclear. You are not saying what you mean. Things like "maintain the logic" and "paths of insert" mean nothing. You are referring to details that you have not explained.  Use more text. Walk us through an example.

Comment: thanks for your patient , i edit the question in understandable manner ? i hope to get a solution for my problem

Comment: _"i want not to lock the update"_ - why?

Comment: I still cannot understand. You are too terse. Show an example, "step by step". Also: you write "logic" but maybe you mean "consistent"?

Comment: Thanks Mr: philipxy -- I meant "consistent"  -- and lastly I find the solution : Point in Time Architecture (PTA) Database

Comment: I suspect your problem is much more basic: "atomic actions" and "concurrency" and "transactions" and "serialization". Good luck.